# How to install build-essentials offline on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I have installed an ubuntu server on shuttle XS35V2 but it doesn't work with the ethernet card thus I can not install build-essentials to upgrade the driver. How to install build essentials offline? I was reading about downloading the .deb files but with all the dependencies for each file it would take ages. Is there a way to download the whole package with all the dependencies or other way to install it? I installed ubuntu from a usb stick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Keryx](http://keryxproject.org/) may work for you. [This AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-offline) explains it's usage a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get --print-uris install build-essential` will give you a list of urls for packages you need to download.  wget those packages from another machine, then sneaker-net those packages to your disconnected machine, and place them into /var/cache/apt/archives

apt-zip is a package which attempts to help you with this process